# Pandas python Random select values from a list colum by another column value

Tags: python, pandas, list, slice

I have a data frame with one column with list values and another column with just 1 item in a list. I want to select out values from column `id` by a condition in column `canceled` then making another column `C` with the selected values.
 Column canceled is the number of canceled codes. 
I need to change the canceled into int and them slice the I'd column with the number of the canceled then return a random number from the column I'd. Ie say code 11AS I will randomly pick 1 id from the array and create another row with canceled Id. For code 22AS since its 0, I will not slice any thing so I will not return any value in the newly created column, so this will go down to all rows.

```
code    canceled  id
xxx     [1.0]     [107385, 128281, 133015]
xxS     [0.0]     [108664, 110515, 113556]
ssD     [1.0]     [134798, 133499, 125396, 114298, 133915]
cvS     [0.0]     [107611]
eeS     [5.0]     [113472, 115236, 108586, 128043, 114106, 10796...
544W    [44.0]    [107650, 128014, 127763, 118036, 116247, 12802.
```

I tried to loop through and slice but i couldn't get what i want. Say `px` is my DataFrame.

```
for i in px['canceled']:
    print(px['id'].str.slice(stop=int(i[0])))
```

Comment: Hello Newton, and welcome to SO. I'm not really following you on the structure of your dataframe, could you provide a minimal example of your dataframe?

Comment: Hi SO, THANKS FOR THE QUICK RESPONSE, i have updated my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please give an example of your expected result?  Sorry, I'm having a hard time following the question.

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in conjunction with [`random.sample`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/#targetText=Python%20%7C%20random.sample()%20function,for%20random%20sampling%20without%20replacement.&targetText=Parameters%3A,tuple%2C%20string%2C%20or%20set.) as follows

```
import random

px['C'] = px.apply(
    lambda datum : random.sample(
        datum.id, k=int(datum.canceled[0])
    ),
    axis = 1
)
```

which may return *(recalling that the column `C` is randomly generated)*

```
code    canceled       id                                         C
xxS     [1.0]          [107385, 128281, 133015]                   [128281]
xxxxS   [0.0]          [108664, 110515, 113556]                   []
ssOD    [1.0]          [134798, 133499, 125396, 114298, 133915]   [114298]
45AS    [0.0]          [107611]                                   []
...     ...            ...                                        ...
```

---

If `int(datum.canceled[0])` returns something greater than the length of `datum.id`, something you can do is returning `datum.id` entirely. As follows

```
def random_codes_sampler(datum):
    ids = datum.id
    nbc = int(datum.canceled[0])
    if nbc >= len(ids):
        return ids
    return random.sample(ids, k=nbc)

px['C'] = px.apply(
    random_codes_sampler, axis = 1
)
```

Comment: Is it what you are asking @Newtorn ?

Comment: Hi thanks for this reply, but actually canceled is not an index it numbers of canceled orders per code, so I want to slice out any random ids from Id column depending on the canceled. The cancelled can also have 44 canceled and above

Comment: See [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58114095/revisions) @Newtorn, is it what you are asking ?

Comment: HI @keepAlive, thanks for the great move...This is considered the right answer. 
This will also help others.

Comment: Hi @keep alive its me Newtorn since i was using my new account by mistake, i couldn't rank the answer as correct since i have few points on that account. 
I have testes it and its working great. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry i didn't know what you meant. Thanks.

Comment: I have one issue if i load more rows. i have like 4000 rows

ValueError: ('Sample larger than population or is negative', 'occurred at index 54')

Comment: @NewtornMosesLwanga it looks like, sometime, the number of canceled codes (the value in the column `canceled`) is greater than the number of values contained in `id`. Do you see what I mean? It is like trying to take, say, 3 values from `['a', 'b']` => it is not possible. Do you want all the values to be taken in such cases ?

Comment: Great thanks this will work for me(still reviewing it now).
if the canceled is greater than the id, then theres an issue with my report, but now every thing works fine. Thanks

Comment: Hi can you help me out on the same problem above, i ran into an issue where i wanted to select values depending on the canceled column but i have another column with ids corresponding with their orders.  each id has its coresponding order

Comment: @NewtornMosesLwanga Sorry. I have no free time currently. You should consider asking a new question, while linking to this post. UPDATE: [you did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863482/python-pandas-select-values-from-another-dataframe-depending-on-the-total-from-a) actually!